# Failure to report number that is too small

Tags: julia

I did the following calculations in Julia

```
z = LinRange(-0.09025000000000001,0.19025000000000003,5)
d = Normal.(0.05*(1-0.95) .+ 0.95.*z .- 0.0051^2/2, 0.0051 .* (similar(z) .*0 .+1))
minimum(cdf.(d, (z[3]+z[2])/2))
```

The problem I have is that the last code sometimes gives me the correct result `4.418051841202834e-239`, sometimes reports the error `DomainError with NaN: Normal: the condition σ >= zero(σ) is not satisfied`. I think this is because `4.418051841202834e-239` is too small. But I was wondering why my code can give me different results.

Comment: Put a reproducible code and read ["How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to points mentioned by others, here are a few more:

Firstly, don't use `LinRange` when numerical accuracy is of importance. This is what the `range` function is for. `LinRange` can be used when numerical precision is of lesser importance, since it is faster. From the docstring of `range`:

> Special care is taken to ensure intermediate values are computed rationally. To avoid this induced overhead, see the `LinRange` constructor.

Example:

```
julia>  LinRange(-0.09025000000000001,0.19025000000000003,5) .- range(-0.09025000000000001,0.19025000000000003,5)
0.0:-3.469446951953614e-18:-1.3877787807814457e-17
```

Secondly, this is a pretty terrible way to create a vector of a certain value:

```
0.0051 .* (similar(z) .*0 .+1)
```

Other's have mentioned `ones`, etc. but I think it's better to use `fill`

```
fill(0.0051, size(z))
```

which directly fills the array with the right value. Perhaps one should use `convert(eltype(z), 0.0051)` inside `fill`.

Thirdly, don't create this vector at *all*! You use broadcasting, so just use the scalar value:

```
d = Normal.(0.05*(1-0.95) .+ 0.95.*z .- 0.0051^2/2, 0.0051) # look! just a scalar!
```

This is how broadcasting works, it expands singleton dimensions implicitly to match other arguments (without *actually* wasting that memory).

Much of the point of broadcasting is that you don't need to create that sort of 'dummy arrays' anymore. If you find yourself doing that, give it another think; constant-valued arrays are inherently wasteful, and you shouldn't need to create them.

Answer (score 2):

The problem in the code is `similar(z)` which produces a vector with undefined entries and is used without initialization. Use `ones(length(z))` instead.

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems:

- Noted by @Dan Getz: `similar` does no initialize the values and quite often unused areas of memory have values corresponding to `NaN`. In that case multiplication by `0` does not help since `NaN * 0 == NaN`. Instead you want to have `ones(eltype(z),size(z))`
- you need to use higher precision than `Float64`. `BigFloat` is one way to go - just you need to remember to call `setprecision(BigFloat, 128)` so you actually control how many bits you use. However, much more time-efficient solution (if you run computations at scale) will be to use a dedicated package such as `DoubleFloats`.

Sample corrected code `using DoubleFloats` below:

```
julia> z = LinRange(df64"-0.09025000000000001",df64"0.19025000000000003",5)
5-element LinRange{Double64, Int64}:
 -0.09025000000000001,-0.020125,0.05000000000000001,0.12012500000000002,0.19025000000000003

julia> d = Normal.(0.05*(1-0.95) .+ 0.95.*z .- 0.0051^2/2, 0.0051 .* ones(eltype(z),size(z)))
5-element Vector{Normal{Double64}}:
 Normal{Double64}(μ=-0.083250505, σ=0.0051)
 Normal{Double64}(μ=-0.016631754999999998, σ=0.0051)
 Normal{Double64}(μ=0.049986995000000006, σ=0.0051)
 Normal{Double64}(μ=0.11660574500000001, σ=0.0051)
 Normal{Double64}(μ=0.18322449500000001, σ=0.0051)

julia> minimum(cdf.(d, (z[3]+z[2])/2))
4.418051841203009e-239
```